# Resume Parent package even Child Package fails

Tags: ssis

I am using Execute Package Task in my job to call my child Packages. I use an execute SQL Task to get my file location and file name to load the file into my tables.

Once I get these details I'll pass this information to my Execute Package task, where upon it calls my child Package.

My query triggers 2 input files, which has to be loaded into my tables.

For example, let us assume `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` has to be loaded. So when `file1.csv` is loading, if there is any error in my child package, my child package fails and my parent package does too. It should not happen like that; if my `file1.csv` fails to load, my child package and parent package should not fail and should continue loading `file2.csv`.

For this I tried changing the Propagate System variable value to false for execute Package task for On Error Event, still I couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can

- Handling the error by setting up a failure path after the task that possibly fails
- Set the MaximumErrorCount to a higher value (click into the background of your control view and go to properties)

Comment: i have set Maximum Error Count to 5